# Java thread safe counter does not work as expected

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I have the following Counter class implemented with AtomicInteger. I copied and pasted this class from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables) article:

```
public class Counter {
  private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public int get() {
      return counter.get();
  }

  public void increment() {
      while (true) {
          int existingValue = get();
          int newValue = existingValue + 1;
          if (counter.compareAndSet(existingValue, newValue)) {
              return;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I wrote the following test to ensure that it is really a thread safe counter:

```
@Test
public void counterWorksAsExpected() {
    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(j -> {
        int threads = 100;
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        IntStream.range(0, threads).forEach(i -> {
            executorService.execute(counter::increment);
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        assertEquals(threads, counter.get());
    });
}
```

However at a certain iteration the assertEquals fails.

I want to know that whether my `Counter` class not thread safe.

Comment: What is the message from the assertion failure?

Comment: Why are you doing that `increment()` logic when the [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) comes with a [`getAndIncrement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement--) / [`incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) method to do the work for you?

Comment: I wrote that I used example from https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shutdown the executor but you don't wait for the submitted tasks to complete before your assertion. Add a call to [`awaitTermination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) before checking the results.